# The numbers on the live Falcon 9 videos

Tags: spacex, falcon-9

In the live Falcon 9 launch videos there are two numbers displayed at the bottom-left corner of the screen.

The two little circular and text gauges that have the units under them.

I guess they are the speed and the altitude?

Are they representing miles or kilometers?

Comment: Are you talking about the two little circular and text gauges *that have the units under them*? And that are labeled *speed and altitude*? https://imgur.com/IPgaNJc

Comment: The text is too small on my screen. I cant read them sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are measured in Metric. Kilometers of altitude and Kilometers/hour of speed.

Comment: just this once... *just this once*... I'm going to let you get away with this "authoritative-sounding yet completely unsourced answer" :-)

Comment: Honestly, I am not sure how otherwise to prove it...

Comment: Well I'm *mostly* just pulling your leg, but would a screen shot from any SpaceX video do it? At least they used to have units displayed right on the screen, and there's the image in OM's comment right under the question, so...